# How to get Html OnClick parameter using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract the NadLanID value from link http://www.yad2.co.il/Nadlan/sales.php?City=%E1%F0%E9%EE%E9%F0%E4+%E2%$

I used Firebug to check the html code which i want to extract, the NadlanId value is at:
`<td onclick="show_ad('2','1','/Nadlan/salesDetails.php','NadlanID','1614569','644');"> בית אריה - יאיר שטרן </td>`

I use the following Scrapy code to check if Scrapy parse the above html code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
    'http://www.yad2.co.il/Nadlan/sales.php?City=%E1%F0%E9%EE%E9%F0%E4+%E2%$
]

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)`
```

But there is no NadlanId in the response.body.

How can i get the NadlanId value?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you want to retrieve javascript function arguments from html `onclick` attribute.

First we find the whole onclick text:

```
text = response.xpath("//td/@onclick").extract_first()
```

Then it's possible to use simple regular expression patterns to find function arguments:

```
# capture anything in between the () of show_ad
< re.findall("show_ad\((.+?)\)", text)[0].split(',')
>["'2'",
  "'1'",
  "'/Nadlan/salesDetails.php'",
  "'NadlanID'",
  "'1614569'",
  "'644'"]
```

Comment: To add to this, I wasn't able to get the page content until I changed the default user agent string. When I tried to mimic Chrome, it started to work. Probably some basic kind of robots protection.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried you solution, while still using f.write(response.body) after re.findall, and i don't get any value. Is this because i need to mimic chrome behavior? and if so how do i do that?